# Interpolation at a face, Finite Volume Method in Computational Fluid Dynamics

Tags: finite-element-method, cfd

I am learning CFD and I have come across an example in which the thermal conductivity needs to be interpolated at a face between two rectangular cells.

The face weighting factor is given as:

$$g = \frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2}$$

where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are cell volumes.  I expected the interpolated value, $k_{1-2}$, would be

$$k_{1-2} = gk_2+(1-g)k_1$$   (linear interpolation)

but instead the author of the example gives:

$$k_{1-2} = \frac{k_1k_2}{[1-g]k_1+gk_2}$$

In the context of finite volume method CFD, what is this method of interpolation called and why would it be preferred over linear interpolation?

(The example I am referring to above is Example 1, Chapter 8, of ***The Finite Volume Method in Computational Fluid Dynamics*** by Moukalled et al.

Comment: If you rearrange it as $1/k_{1{-}2} = g/k_1 + (1-g)/k_2$ it might be more obvious why that is the right form to use.

Comment: Conductivity in series is added by harmonic means. So inverse of sum of distance weighted inverses.

Comment: Ah!  I was so focused on getting an interpolated value at the boundary that I didn't think of it as the conductivity of two materials in series.  Thank you very much for the help!